# Maximum size of a command on an RLC Club Deluxe 2

Tags: repeater

With reference to an RLC Club Deluxe 2 repeater controller:

1. What is the maximum size of a command?
2. What is the maximum size of a macro?

The manual does mention "Limits on Macros" but all it says is:

> Since one macro can call another, you may wonder if macro 500 could
>   call 501, which could call 502, which could call 503, etc., until you
>   recalled 100 macros or so. The answer is not quite. There are other
>   limits. One is that if the total time it takes the processor to decode
>   and execute the whole chained macro sequence is more than one half
>   second or so, the controller may reset itself. It is unlikely that you
>   will ever reach this limit (it would probably take more than 20 macros
>   are hooked together even come close to this limit). The other limit
>   restricts how deeply the macros can be nested (called from another
>   macro). This is not a limit on how many commands can be called inside
>   of a macro. It is not a limit on how many macros can be executed from
>   one Mac. It is a limit on one macro calling another macro that calls
>   another macro that calls another macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each macro can hold 100 bytes.

There are 200 standard commands, another 300 that are for internal macros and another 500 for user macros.

OP Edit: I was able to find a [searchable version of the manual](http://s230753592.onlinehome.us/ftp/rlc-club/manuals/dlx2_215_searchable.pdf). There I found only one reference to a maximum command length, and it also happens to mention a macro maximum length.

> The message length is limited to the maximum command length (about 200
>   characters) or if used in a macro, by the space left in a macro (less
>   than 100 characters).

For the macro size limit, we refer to a URL in a comment by [glenn-w9iq](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/9493/glenn-w9iq), which takes us to the [RLC-Club FAQs](http://s230753592.onlinehome.us/wiki/index.php?title=RLC-Club_FAQs#Q:_What_are_the_macro_size_limits_on_the_RLC-Club.3F) page on the RLC wiki.  It says:

> Q: What are the macro size limits on the RLC-Club?
>
> A: All RLC-Club macros can hold up to 100 bytes. A byte of macro
>   storage roughly corresponds with a digit stored in it, but that
>   relationship isn't exact. The easiest way to find out how much space a
>   macro takes is to program it, then ask the controller how full the
>   macro is with command 054. If you want to figure it out manually, use
>   the equation 1 + (3 * NumCommands) + TotalDataDigits =
>   MacroSizeInBytes. For example:
>
> ```
>  055 500                 ; erase macro - doesn't use any space
>  056 500 036 001 002 003 ; speak "one two three" - one command, 9 data digits
>  056 500 038             ; be quiet - one command, no data digits
>  056 500 000 12          ; connect ports 1 and 2 - one command, 2 data digits
>  ;
>  Total space used = 1 + ( 3 * 3 ) + 11 = 21 bytes.
> ```

So for lack of anything more specific, it appears these are the answers:

1. The maximum size of a command is "about 200 characters".
2. The maximum size of a macro is 100 bytes which is "less than 100 characters".

Comment: So if I'm entering 036 001 (announce "one") as the content of the macro, how many bytes are in that command and how is that determined?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Not necessary obviously, but thought I'd check. Just figured if you did then there might be other good information I'd find there as well.

Comment: @Joshua check out their wiki: http://s230753592.onlinehome.us/wiki/index.php?title=RLC-Club_FAQs

Comment: @Joshua Why did you delete your answer and edit its content into this answer? That doesn't look like a particularly better result.

Comment: Because his answer was first and was correct.  All I did was expound upon it.  That is the correct way to handle that situation on StackExchange sites.